# Amazon EC2 instances changes server time/date on reboots and other time weirdness

Tags: amazon-ec2, time, time-synchronization, timezone

I have a windows instance up in EC2.  I manually set the timezone to Pacific.

1) For some reason using window's built in time sync doesn't work in the instance...but whatever. I turn off automatic time syncing...

but 2) On reboot the time on the server changes! For example, if i reboot it at 4PM on Wednesday, when the server comes back up it will read 12 noon on Thursday!

As a result any access to Amazon's other services like SImpleDB fail because the timestamps generated are too far off the current time.

Has anyone seen this or figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Go to [this link](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=132397) on amazon's aws forum there is post by Nancy W. Abramson that might solve your problem. OR there is problem with AMD Hardware mentioned at blog.dt.org in time-and-clock-issues-in-windows-based-ec2-instances blog post. Hope this help you.